# AWS APIGateway API - Upload pdf (binary) file - Getting Unsupported Media Type Error

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, pdf, upload, gateway

I am trying to run the sample api code given in aws website to put the file.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-content-encodings-examples-image-lambda.html

I am using the following command to run the api

`https://XXXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXX/XXXXXX/?key=abc.pdf`

my curl script is below:

```
response=curl -X PUT -s ${URL} -H "accept: application/json" -H "content-type:application/octet-stream" -H "x-api-key: ${apiKey}" --data-binary @abc.pdf
```

I keep getting the same response:

> {"message": "Unsupported Media Type"}

Any help on this is appreciated.

Now I am getting this error:

{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'JVBERi0xLjUNJeLjz9MNCjE3MDIgMCBvYmoNPDwvTGluZWFyaXplZCAxL0wgNjQ1MDI4L08gMTcwNC9FIDI3MDgyMS9OIDcvVCA2NDQxODAvSCBbIDEzOTUgNjMzXT4\': was expecting (\'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: [B@6c5d8253; line: 1, column: 129]"}

My request template is like below: 
  requestTemplates:
                  application/json: |-
                    {
                      "fileName": "$input.params('fileName')",
                      "body" : $input.body
                    }

Answer (score 0):

Please try by modifying your content-type to 'application/pdf', which is the content type for PDF.

Comment: I did try that option too. In the binary-media-types, I have                          
       - application/octet-stream
        - application/pdf
        - image/jpeg
I tried using curl with both 'application/octet-stream' and 'application/pdf' , but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it in Postman because it seems like it should be application/pdf instead.

-H "content-type:application/pdf"